# How do I deduce auto before a function is called?

Tags: c++, function, auto, c++14, return-type-deduction

while experimenting with [function return type deduction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B14#Function_return_type_deduction)

```
auto func();

int main() { func(); }

auto func() { return 0; }
```

**error: use of ‘auto func()’ before deduction of ‘auto’**

Is there a way to use this feature without needing to specify the definition before the call?  With a large call tree, it becomes complicated to re-arrange functions so that their definition is seen before all of the places they are called.  Surely an evaluation could be held off until a particular function definition was found and auto could then be deduced.

Comment: Why would you use `auto`? This kind of return type deduction is not meant for day-to-day use, but mostly inside generic library code.

Comment: @stefan I thought there might be a "read all the code first, before you go evaluating it" option.

Comment: I don't think it's possible, see the current draft [decl.spec.auto]/11 "If the type of an entity with an undeduced placeholder type is needed to determine the type of an expression,
the program is ill-formed."

Comment: Why are you using auto in this way at all?  What problem are you trying to solve with it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, there is not.

Even ignoring the practical problems (requiring multi-pass compilation, ease of making undecidable return types via mutually recursive type definitions, difficulty in isolating source of compilation errors when everything resolves, etc), and the design issues (that forward declaration is nearly useless), C++11 was designed with ease of implementation in mind.  Things that made it harder to write a compiler needed strong justification.

The myriad restrictions on `auto` mean that it was really easy to slide it into existing compilers: it is among the most supported C++11 features in my experience.  C++14 relaxes many of the restrictions, but does not go nearly as far as you describe.  Each relaxation requires justification and confidence that it will be worth the cost to compiler writers to implement.

I would not even want that feature at this time, as I like the signatures of my functions to be deducible at the point I call them, at the very least.

Answer (score 5):

No, this simply isn't possible with C++'s compilation model. Remember that the definition of `func` may appear in a different file, or even inside a library somewhere. The return type must be known if you are going to use it.

Answer (score 5):

The relevant paper is [N3638](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3638.html) which prohibits use of functions declared with an `auto` return prior to knowning the return type. The paper actually makes a point, however, that as soon as the return type could be deduced from the function body it can also be called! Thus, a function with an `auto` return can actually be recursive.

Answer (score 1):

I would avoid automatic deduction of the return type in functions in as much as you can. While it might appear to be a *nice* feature that eases the need to actually figure out the type, it is not a simple feature to use, and it has limitations (the return type cannot be used in an SFINAE context, it requires the instantiation of the function...)

The answer to your question is that the compiler cannot infer the type without seeing the definition, and the processing is always done in a top-down approach.